# how to start rostest file on startup?

Tags: rostest, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anybody implemented the rostest file that would be launched on startup? All I did now was to type the command `make run_tests` in the `build` folder of the workspace manually. I want the file to be automatically run when my machine boots up. Any help would be appreciated, and let me know if you need any details from me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282967/how-to-start-rostest-file-on-startup?/) by [chanhyeoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/29607/chanhyeoni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-02-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-02-16**:
rostest was not designed to be used like this, and there's probably a better way to do it. What are you actually trying to do? (This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) )

**Comment by [chanhyeoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/29607/chanhyeoni/) on 2018-02-16**:
I want my machine to auto-check every component (e.g. thruster and gps) in order to ensure that each part works properly and provide end users with a checklist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rostest` is meant for running unit and integration tests, either manually or within a Continuous Integration process. It isn't designed for running live tests at startup.

I'd suggest you use the [diagnostics](http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostics) and [self_test](http://wiki.ros.org/self_test) packages for reporting issues to users and running self-tests at startup.

the diagnostics package in particular is designed for continuous monitoring and reporting of issues, and provides the [diagnostic_aggregator](http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostic_aggregator) for validating and formatting diagnostics, and [rqt_robot_monitor](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_robot_monitor) for displaying those diagnostics to users.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2